# WorkManager - CoroutineWorker with API calls

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-workmanager

I have a Worker whose responsibility is to send an FCM push. So, I do follow below steps:

1. Do an API call to get the FCM token of target user
2. Then send a push

Here is the code:

```
class CreateOrderFCMWorker(
    context: Context,
    workerParameters: WorkerParameters
) : CoroutineWorker(
    context,
    workerParameters
) {

    @InternalCoroutinesApi
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        val tokens = fetchTokens() // API call
        sendPush(tokens)
        return Result.success()
    }

    private suspend fun fetchTokens(locationId: String): List<String> {
        return suspendCoroutine {
            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                FetchTokensUseCase().collect { result ->
                    if (result is Result.Success) {
                        if (result.data.isNotEmpty()) {
                            val fcmTokens = result.data.map { it.fcmToken }
                            it.resume(fcmTokens)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun sendOrderCreatedPush(fcmTokens: List<String>) {
        // Code to send FCM push
    }
}
```

Notice that, `fetchTokens()` calls a usecase which returns a `Flow<List<String>>`. As WorkManager's `doWork()` needs to be syncronous, I have to use `suspendCoroutine`.

Is there any other way to solve it? I don't like using `GlobalScope` in the code. How can I make it the proper production quality code?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using any of the other terminal operations on Flow such as `first()` or `takeUntil()`?

Comment: Because I am an idiot. Thanks for the quick reply Ian.

Answer (score 0):

`fetchTokens()` could be modified to:

```
private suspend fun fetchTokens(locationId: String) = FetchTokensUseCase().takeWhile{ it !is Result.Success }.last().let{ result ->
    result.data.map { it.fcmToken }
}
```